# params passed to input paths' wildcard

Tags: parameters, snakemake

I am working on a pipeline in Snakemake 7.2.1.
I have a list of parameters saved in `config.yaml` and I want to pass them to a script. The same config file also contains a list that I need to use to run the rule.
Example of `config.yaml`:

```
entry0:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
entry1:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
entry2:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
```

Made it this far:

```
configfile: "config.yaml"
output_folder="/output/path"
variable = config.get("entry0")

rule all:
  input:
    expand(f"{output_folder}/newfile_{{variable}}_{{p1}}_{{p2}}.txt",
           variable = variable, p1 = config.get("entry1"), p2 = config.get("entry2"))

rule run_with_parameters:
  input:
    f"{output_folder}/file_{{variable}}.txt"
  output:
    f"{output_folder}/newfile_{{variable}}.{{params.param1}}_{{params.param2}}.txt"
  params:
    param1 = config.get("entry1"),
    param2 = config.get("entry2")
  shell:
    "awk -v p1={params.param1} -v p2={params.param1} {input} > {output}"
```

But this doesn't work, as the parameters get passed to `variable` in the input too:

```
MissingInputException in line XX of Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule snp_stats_sibs_all_snps:
    output: /output/path/newfile_1_1_1.txt
    wildcards: variable=1.1_1
    affected files:
        /output/path/file_1.1_1.txt
```

I also tried `Paramspace`, with similar results (everything gets expanded in `input:` too).

I would like the `params` to be parsed just in the output where I am calling them, as the 3 input files are the same.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Snakemake automatically deduces wildcards from the filename. E.g., your rule all requests the file `/output/path/newfile_1_2_3.txt`.

If you have a rule `abc` that can match the filename with wildcards, e.g.

```
rule abc
  output:
    "output/path/newfile_{v1}_{v2}_{v3}.txt"
```

, then that rule will be used to produce the requested file.

In your example, this means that you don't need to lookup the parameters from your config file in the rule `run_with_parameters`, since you can infer the parameters from the filename.

If I understand your question correctly, then your example would look like this:

```py
configfile: "config.yaml"
output_folder="/output/path"

rule all:
  input:
    expand(f"{output_folder}/newfile_{{variable}}_{{p1}}_{{p2}}.txt",
           variable = config["entry0"], p1 = config["entry1"], p2 = config["entry2"])

rule run_with_parameters:
  input:
    f"{output_folder}/file_{{v1}}.txt"
  output:
    f"{output_folder}/newfile_{{v1}}_{{p1}}_{{p2}}.txt"
  shell:
    "awk -v p1={p1} -v p2={p2} {input} > {output}"
```

I've also replaced `config.get()` with `config[]`, but either works.

Comment: How do I pass the parameters to the rule, though?